# Which regression should I use for a 0-5 scale IV (taking any values) and an interval DV?

Tags: regression, stata

It might sound like an easy question. What makes me confused is that the independent variable takes any values between 0 and 5 including the numbers such as 1.987. So, I am not sure if I should consider it as an ordinal variable.

Comment: So the outcome is on an interval?  Like 0 to 10 and can be any number in that interval?

Comment: It takes any values between 0 to 5 such as 0, 3.562, 1.97 etc. @DemetriPananos

Comment: Rescale the outcome to be between 0 and 1 and you can use beta regression.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your dependent variable?

Comment: My dependent variable is an interval (number of terrorist attacks in each country) @PsychometStats

Comment: try beta regression as Demetri Pananos mentioned or OLS

Comment: May I ask a more detailed question if you have time? @PsychometStats

Comment: @Reyhan go for it

Comment: For my independent variable, I have country-level and yearly data (2000-2020) about repression. For each country, repression takes any values between -5 to 5 (including 0.78, -3.41, etc.)

I have country-level and yearly data (2000-2020) about terrorist incidents for my dependent variable. For each country, it takes any interval values (0, 1, 10, 125).

Which regression method should I use? Should I use time-series analysis? Thanks in advance. @PsychometStats

Comment: @Reyhan to be completely honest with you, I would post this as an individual thread and asked. That way you can get more perspectives as to what analysis to do. Also, a thought for you: What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve in your modelling? Annual changes? Or some sort of understanding as to what explains the most variance in your Dependent variable

Comment: @PsychometStats Thank you for your response. I asked this question in a separate thread but nobody made any suggestions. I am trying to understand the variance in my DV. I mean I want to observe the relationship between my DV and IV. It is difficult to grasp this without knowing which method to use.

Answer (score 0):

follow the lead of Demetri and rescale the variable to be between 0 and 1. Then you can use beta regression but you also have the fractional logit model in your arsenal, see
[here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdfdirect/10.1002/%28SICI%291099-1255%28199611%2911%3A6%3C619%3A%3AAID-JAE418%3E3.0.CO%3B2-1).

I hope this helps.

Comment: See also from 22 years earlier 
R. W. M. Wedderburn. 1974. Quasi-Likelihood Functions, Generalized Linear Models, and the Gauss-Newton Method.  _Biometrika_ 61: 439-447   http://www.jstor.org/stable/2334725

Comment: Thank you very much to you both.